# JS - Window width function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a responsive navigation menu.
a button is used to toggle the menu in and out. This  is working fine.

I added an exception, where if the window exceeds a certain width, the menu closes, however this is not working at all. I can't find what is wrong with this code.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menubutton").click(function(){
        $(".respmenu-gen").toggleClass("respmenu-opn respmenu-cls");
    });
    if ($(window).width() > 767) {
        $(".respmenu-gen").removeClass("respmenu-opn").addClass("respmenu-cls")
    };
});
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/76amgsb8/

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a viewport meta tag? If so what does it say?

Comment: yup:    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: Are you only concerned with the behavior occurring on page load?

Comment: Put in some alerts within your document ready code to check if its actually getting there (or console.log()) and also (in Firefox) use Ctrl + Shift + J to view the error log. It will show you if other parts of your Javascript are stopping it working.

Comment: @lomteslie not particularily.

Comment: @Ukuser32 good debug advice. Will give a go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `window.resize()` method.
Check it out [here](https://api.jquery.com/resize/).

What you essentially do here is when content loads you check the width of window, just once. You should be bound on the resize event.

So, you can essentially do the following:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
  if (viewportWidth > 767)
      $(".respmenu-gen").removeClass("respmenu-opn").addClass("respmenu-cls")
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menubutton").click(function(){
        $(".respmenu-gen").toggleClass("respmenu-opn respmenu-cls");
    });
});
```

If you are bound to work with JavaScript about responsiveness, I would suggest to use the `window.matchMedia(mediaQueryString)` way though, as relying on jQuery `resize()` won't give you exact results. `window.matchMedia()` is more powerfull and you can also benefit from familiar CSS3 media queries.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

**Update**

Should always rely on CSS3 media queries though and not JavaScript (except you want to achieve something that is not possible through CSS and the only workaround is JavaScript).

Comment: aha! yes perfect. resize() does the trick! Wouldn't have thought of it......looking into the matchMedia() way. Seems powerful! will definitely use in future projects

Comment: Does this load on the initial page load though?

Comment: this can also be done with css media queries, for example use it to set css to .respmenu-opn. As you don't change classes an open menu will close/reopen as you raise/lower window width: https://jsfiddle.net/76amgsb8/1/

Comment: Of course this can be done with CSS media queries, the OP's question though is about JavaScript

Comment: it is tagged with CSS though ... but I should have put the comment under the question

Answer (score -1):

use the code below:

```
 var window_width = $(window).width();
if (window_width < 767) {
    $(".respmenu-gen").removeClass("respmenu-opn").addClass("respmenu-cls");
}
```

Comment: looked promising...but alas, no success

Comment: insert the full code in jsfiddle or codepen to get a better help